# как в wpf получить значение комбобокс когда там мультибиндинг

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

как в wpf получить значение комбобокс когда там мультибиндинг

```
<ComboBox x:Name="TransferNameCombobox" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Кому отправить">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1} {2}">
                                <Binding Path="surname"/>
                                <Binding Path="name"/>
                                <Binding Path="patronymic"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
```

c#

```
TransferNameCombobox.ItemsSource = allClients;
```

Я пробовал текст, селектид айтем и т.д. все выдает либо пустоту либо [image: тип класса]

[image: Класс]

Comment: `либо тип класса` - ну так в этом классе у вас и должны быть все эти свойства, с нужными значениями.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я не так давно изучаю может чего не понимаю. Я получаю тип класса. Элементы хранятся в списке не понимаю как это поможет. То что список именно этого типа и так понятно)

Comment: Момент в том, что вопрос то должен быть простой. Получить значение поля должно мне кажется быть в стандартном наборе. В виду того что я не так давно учусь мне кажется я просто не знаю какой то метод)))

Comment: Как метод вы хотите я не пойму? Вот у вас есть коллекция, условно `List<Person> Items`, сам класс персон условно `class Person { string Name {get'set;'} }`, вы привязываете `ComboBox` к этой коллекции, допустим `<ComboBox ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">`, далее вы через `MultiBinding` задаете привязки к свойствам класса `Person`, вот условно сейчас ваш этап. Далее вы получаете объект, для этого делаете свойство выбранного объекта (`Person SelectedItem {get;set;}`, привязываете к нему `ComboBox` примерно так `<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">`

Comment: Все, дальше где надо просто обращаетесь к свойству `SelectedItem` забирая из него нужные свойства, например `var personName = SelectedItem.Name;`. И вот ваш `либо тип класса`, из которого просто забирается нужное значение, в чем проблема то тогда я не пойму? Если надо это также объединить в одно целое, ну либо `var result = SelectedItem.surname + " " + SelectedItem.name`, либо `var result = $"{SelectedItem.surname} {SelectedItem.name}";`. То есть сами объединяете эти свойства, а не пытаетесь объединенное из интерфейса забрать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ
 Я искренне не понимаю...Слова знакомые но как вместе станут не че не понятно))) Я не понимаю куда это писать Person SelectedItem {get;set;} внутрь класса не встанет  хамл тоже.

Comment: Я тоже искренне не понимаю, ибо вы в вопросе прямым текстом написали `выдает либо пустоту либо тип класса`, то есть, вы получаете класс, из которого просто можете вытянуть нужное свойство (`класс.name` например), но почему-то это не делаете.... А выше, я вам не шаговую инструкцию написал, а примерно то, что у вас должно быть, а как на самом деле - вы не показываете.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Он конкретно выдает вот это homework_12.Client. Client это название класса. Написание Client.surname не чего не даст. Список клиент хранится в List<Client> allClients. Отредактировал. Добавил скрин класса и что получаю

Comment: Подумайте логически `List<Client> allClients` - если напишете `allClients.name` - имя кого вы должны получить? Первого клиента? Может 10-го? Правильно, вы так не получите вообще ничего, ибо это коллекция, а не клиент. Чтобы получить конкретного клиента, вам надо из коллекции его достать, например, по индексу `allClients[0].name` - получите имя первого из коллекции. Тоже самое и с `ComboBox`, почему из него хотите получить сразу клиента? А какого? Наверно того, который выбрали, верно? Ну так `.SelectedItem`, только он `object`, а значит надо привести к типу, например: `... is Client client`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Благодарю. Сделал не совсем так. Обратился сразу к SelectedIndex но суть та же

Comment: Пожалуйста вставляйте код текстом, а не картинкой.

Answer (score 0):

```
int personId = TransferNameCombobox.SelectedIndex;
            string personName = allClients[personId].name;
            MessageBox.Show($"{personName}");
```

Comment: можно проще `MessageBox.Show((TransferNameCombobox.SelectedItem as Client)?.name ?? "ничего не выбрано");`. Кстати, публичные свойства в классах рекомендуется с большой буквы называть.